# Twitch: Read chat with php script

Tags: php, chat, twitch

I would like to access a twitch chat with a php script to retrieve the latest chat messages. But the twitch api seems not to support chat access. does anyone know a way how i can get the latest chat messages of a channel via a php script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitch uses a standard protocol for chat. Specifically IRC. Therefore, an API is not needed. Here's the link: http://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/1302780-twitch-irc